Which specifications are allowed to deviate with MOSFET?
Please tell me which specifications are allowed to deviate with MOSFET?
I need to buy MOSFET, in my case AUIRFS4610. but that one is not available, however there are substitutes. but I am not 100% sure if I will find a MOSFET with the same specifications. So I'm interested in which specifications can differ?
AUIRFS4610 is VDSS 100V, ID 73A
And at this moment I can buy MOSFET with:

VDSS 75V, ID 100A
VDSS 80V, ID 100A
VDSS 100V, ID 57A
VDSS 60V, ID 83A
VDSS 150V, ID 79A

Thank you

As a quick estimate, you can buy MOSFETs with absolute maximum ratings above your required conditions but hey, it really depends on your intended application and it is hard to say what other parameters would suffer. Can you share more details regarding the use case?

Then sounds like option 5 is the safest option to choose to avoid damaging the MOSFET within your tool.

Infineon IRFS4610TRLPBF looks like a decent alternative without comparing the datasheet values too deep. You need to define what parameters are critical to your application and compare the datasheets for those.

VGS rating and RON are also some critical parameters that you need to look at.

I don't think this should be downvoted, it's a very common question; even though it's not nearly as simple as it sounds.

This is a very common problem, but unfortunately there is no easy answer.
What specs are important will depend on the circuit. Mosfets also have a LOT of specs, not just those 3. Any of them may be important depending on the circuit.
The practical answer here is that you need an engineer familiar with the circuit to pick a new mosfet. You may be able to pick a new fet yourself in the future if the engineer writes detailed requirements for you.
